# RTMP Streaming to Twitch

Tags: linux, debian, nginx, streaming, rtmp

I'm streaming using OBS on Windows (QuickSync), pushing 20k bitrate to 2nd PC based on Linux (Debian Jessie 8.4.0, 64bit) via Gigabit Ethernet.

The Debian system runs a minimal installation without X server (just CLI), where I compiled and installed nginx 1.10 with rtmp module.

Debian Jessie specs:

- AMD Athlon X2 64 4200
- 2GB RAM
- Regular 7200 RPM hdd

nginx.conf:

```
root@streamer:~# cat /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
worker_processes 2;

error_log logs/error.log debug; events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

rtmp {
  server {
  listen 1935;
  chunk_size 4000;

  application transcode {
  live on;
  record off;
  exec avconv -re -i rtmp://localhost:1935/transcode/1234 -c:v libx264  -preset superfast -g 60 -keyint_min 30 -b:v 2800k -minrate 2800k -maxrate 2800k  -s 1280x720 -r 30 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/1234;
  }

  application live {
  live on;
  record off;
  push rtmp://live-ams.twitch.tv/app/STREAMKEY;
  }
}
}
```

My question:
I can stream video using SUPERFAST preset without stutters, but when I go to VERYFAST, video on twitch is stopping every like 5 seconds for a while (not buffering).

Is that Athlon not enough to stream video with veryfast - faster preset? This machine got literally only needed stuff on the CLI Debian just to stream, so I'm not losing any resources.

I was quite sure I can push the quality as faster/veryfast with this rig.

Could anyone elaborate on the topic?

Comment: and could switching to ffmpeg from avconv could do any changes in performance?

Comment: After using ffmpeg 3.0.22 backports on Jessie i can say there is a slight performance boost and the quality of stream seems to be better, but still the veryfast preset is killing dual core cpu with 200% usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing quite a lot of research, it seems that Athlon X2 64 4200+ is not capable of pushing 720p video at 30 frame rate at veryfast/faster preset.

I need something stronger to maintain the transmission, so the CPU need to have more power.